# Can the limit of a product exist even if the limit of one of the factors doesn't?

Tags: real-analysis

Show an example where $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ does not exist and $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$ exists but $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)g(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Let $g = 0$ and $f$ your favorite discontinuous function.

Comment: what about one where both lim x->c of f(x) and of g(x) do not exist but the lim x->x f(x)*g(x) does exist?

Comment: @Johnny Take $f$ to be zero for $x < 0$, and something bad for $x > 0$. Let $g$ be zero for $x > 0$ and bad for $x < 0$.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer to the question posed by Johnny in the comment section under T. Bongers answer. Take $f=g$ with $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational and $-1$ if $x$ is irrational. The limit exists nowhere for both but $f(x)g(x)=1$ for all $x$.